# Highlight / emphasize a string in tcblisting

Tags: listings, highlighting, tcolorbox

How can I emphasize a string in a **tcblisting** like it is possible with the "moredelim" option in a `lstlisting` environment? The goal ist to be able to situational epmhasize arbitrary strings in a **tcblisting**.

With the `listings` package I can do:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinestyle{somebox}{
    frame=single,
    moredelim=**[is][\color{green}]{@}{@},
}    

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=somebox]
    black @green@ black
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, I want to use the `listings` library along with `tcolorbox` like this:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{somebox}{
    listing only,
    listing options={style=tcblatex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{somebox}
black green black
\end{somebox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But `tcolorbox` does not know "moredelim":

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{somebox}{
    listing only,
    listing options={style=tcblatex},
    moredelim=**[is][\color{green}]{@}{@}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{somebox}
black @green@ black
\end{somebox}
\end{document}
```

Error is:

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/moredelim', to which you pmisspelled it. \begin{somebox}

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must pass listings options inside the argument of the `listings options` key. If you want to change the listings options locally you could pass it through an optional argument (put braces around the argument of moredelim to protect the []):

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcblisting{somebox}[1][]{
    listing only,
    listing options={style=tcblatex,moredelim={**[is][\color{green}]{@}{@}},#1},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{somebox}
black @green@ black
\end{somebox}


\begin{somebox}[moredelim={**[is][\color{red}]{@}{@}}]
black @green@ black
\end{somebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can define a new listing language

```
\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}
{
    moredelim=**[is][\color{green}]{@}{@}
}
```

and use it inside the `listing options` of your `\newtcblisting`

```
\newtcblisting{somebox}{
    listing only,
    listing options={style=tcblatex,language=mylang}
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}
{
    moredelim=**[is][\color{green}]{@}{@}
}

\newtcblisting{somebox}{
    listing only,
    listing options={style=tcblatex,language=mylang}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{somebox}
black @green@ black
\end{somebox}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: That works perfect and answers my question. What I have not asked for but I want to add here: If you do not want to define a completely new language but just want to extend an existing one, you can write e. g. `\lstdefinelanguage{mylang}[]{python}`.